# windows phone 7, panorama touch events?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, gesture, panorama-control

I have a panorama control with 3 panorama items in it. I want to create a function where if a user taps on any panorama item, it changes the pictures of the ones currently off the screen.

I Wont confuse everyone with the details of it, but simply put is there a surefire way to get this to work? Can the touch/tap event be used in a panorama control to dynamically change the image?

Answer (score 1):

In the event handler for the tap gesture just update the `Source` of each of the other images.
There should be no reason why this wouldn't work.